# CSS Keyframe I cannot seem to remove an artifact

Tags: css

I have a simple scaling animation applied to a circle using keyframes.

There is an unexpected and undesirable line that scales with the circle in Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) and not in Firefox or Safari.

I cannot remove it - do you know how to? I have tried adding border: 0 to the various divs unsuccessfully.

```css
#parent { overflow: hidden; background: #F0F4FF; height: 500px; width: 100%; position: relative; user-select: none; margin-block-end: 5rem; z-index: 3; }

.child { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.child .inner { background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #D90368 20%, #F0F4FF 20%); }

.inner { position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; animation: circle 2s linear infinite; display: block; height:100%; width: 100%; content: " "; }

@keyframes circle { 0% { transform: scale(0.5) } 50% { transform: scale(1.2) } 80% { transform: scale(0.95) } 100% { transform: scale(1.0) } }
```

```html
  <div id='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      <span class='inner'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Here is a screenshot mid-animation of the line that follows the scale animation]

[image: Second screenshot]

I have tried to search SO however I find a lot of similar line / scale / keyframe posts but these are intentional line animation posts.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any line in the code snippet?

Comment: in your gradient make one the last 20% to be 21% .. never use equal value in gradient, always slightly different

Comment: @AmeyaRane thank you for your comment, I have added to my original post an image of the line artefact and clarified that it seems to be browser-specific "Chrome".

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your comment, I tried your suggestion and it does not fix my quandary.

Comment: Do you see the same issue when you try running your code snippet in the question? I'm not seeing the issue reproducing on Chrome.

Comment: i am using the lastest version of chrome but not seeing the line in the provided snippet

Comment: @DBS Thank you for your question - yes, I even see it running in the small "run code snippet". I have updated my original post with an image confirming the artefact.

Comment: @RamondeVries Thank you for your comment, that is very reassuring, although not sure I can push to prod ;) as I can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the line to on Chrome. So I edited the code a bit, and the line was gone. Not sure what the problem was, just a different solution:
The html:

```
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="child">
        <div class="inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0f4ff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  margin-block-end: 5rem;
  z-index: 3;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
    background-color: #d90368;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 5rem);
  top: calc(50% - 5rem);
  animation: circle 2s linear infinite;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes circle {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```